# Not saving correctly in Firebase DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
function saveDB()
{
var assmtEid=7;
var username="aashiquemd2212";
var myvar="14ca120";
    var ref2 = database.ref(username+'/course/'+myvar+'/ExerciseTable/'+assmtEid+'/');
    
    // var refe = database.ref(username+'/course/'+myvar+'/ExerciseTable');
    // refe.child(assmtEid).set({
    // Exid: assmtEid,
    // Ename: displayname,
    // Etotal: "20"
    // });
    var tb=document.getElementsByClassName("tbody")[0];
    var len=tb.rows.length;
    for(var l=0;l<len;l++)
    {
        var tno=l+1;
        var tnam=tb.rows[l].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value;
        var tmark=tb.rows[l].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].value;
        console.log("**"+tno+"**"+tnam+"**"+tmark+"**");
        // ref2.child(tno).set({
        // cid:tno,
        // cname:tnam,
        // ctotal:tmark
        // });// criteria save
         var kn=document.getElementById("dtable"+l+"").rows.length;
         
         for(var lent=0;lent<kn;lent++)
         {
             var mtd1=lent+1;
             var mtd2=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[l].rows[lent].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value;
             var mtd3=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[l].rows[lent].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].value;
            console.log("--"+mtd1+"--"+mtd2+"--"+mtd3+"--");
             // ref2.child(tno+"/"+mtd1).set({
             // did:mtd1,
             // dname:mtd2,
             // dmark:mtd3
             // });// descriptive save

         }
         console.log("#####################");
    }


}
```

While running this code it properly shows the output in the console. But when I remove the commented lines and run the code it inserts with extra nodes. I couldn't find the error, what causes this extra node addition. Please help me.
[image: This shows properly on the console]But while removing the commented lines and run, it saves Firebase with extra nodes.Update button triggers the saveDB function.
[image: After clicking the update button.]

Comment: yes if u uncomment then you will be creating a new child and setting it with the values inside `set()`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes, I know it, but instead of saving 2 nodes it saves 7 nodes. I asking the reason for it. But it shows properly in the console. But it saves wrongly in the Firebase

Answer (score 1):

Firebase real-time database has no native support for arrays, so it uses integer keys to store them. To me it looks like this is what's happening here.
Try using different keys, e.g. `k7` instead of integers.

Comment: My point is that Firebase might *think* you are saving an array because the way you save your data is how an array would be saved.